# Is the magnetic flux density B constant? Is the magnetic flux constant?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am working on a project design for Uni and I am stuck.

In a magnetic circuit is either the magnetic flux or the magnetic flux density B constant? This magnetic circuit has all different cross section areas and air gaps.
I need to calculate the Magnetic Force generated by the circuit and also N*i= Φ1 * R1 +  ...   (N beeing nº of spirals in a coil and R the reluctance). I am stuck in a loop because I think neither B nor Φ are constant.

I was told to use saturation flux density (Bsat=2.13) of the material to jump start the calculations, but I am stuck on the question at hand.
Any insight would be appreciated and sorry for the lack of understanding in electromagnetism.

Edit: This circuit is for an eletromagnetic brake. I have all of the dimensions and reluctances. I also have an estimated current and Number of spires that depending on the results of the question I will have to revise in order too see if they are appropriate. The final objective is for the magnetic force to be equal or larger than a known value.

[image]

Comment: I believe you should share some more information in order for people here to be able to provide some help. Do you have any sketch or additional information about your circuit?

Answer (score 0):

Since magnetic field lines form closed loops, one might expect that the flux around an ideal “magnetic circuit” should constant.  In practice it's likely that some of the field line may stray outside of your “circuit”.  The amount of “leakage” will depend on the design of your circuit and the materials used.

Comment: So if I consider the flux to be constant, the saturation flux density (Bsat) will correspond to the section of the magnetic circuit has the smallest cross section area?

Comment: That would be true if most of the field lines stay within the magnetic circuit.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.